# If $| \alpha(t) \rangle = e^{-i\omega t} |\alpha_0 \rangle$, then why is there time dependence in expected values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, time-evolution

The time evolution of a coherent state $| \alpha(t) \rangle$ is given by:

$$| \alpha(t) \rangle = e^{-i\omega t} |\alpha_0 \rangle$$

So then it seems to me that it should be

$$\langle \alpha(t)| = \langle \alpha_0 | e^{i\omega t} $$

But then for any expected value, there would be

$$\langle \alpha(t)| \hat{A}| \alpha(t) \rangle = \langle \alpha_0|e^{i\omega t} \hat{A}e^{-i\omega t} |\alpha_0 \rangle =\langle \alpha_0| \hat{A}| \alpha_0 \rangle $$

which is obviously false, what's the mistake? The exponential factors are after all just constants so I think I am allowed to move them around the operator $\hat{A}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clear this up: the OP's expression for coherent states is plain wrong. The correct time evolution reads
$$
\left|\alpha\right> = e^{-i\omega t/2} \left|\alpha_0e^{-i\omega t}\right>
$$
as per e.g. [this resource](http://www.fysik.su.se/~hansson/KFT2/extra%20notes/cstates%20copy.pdf). The additional phase of $e^{-i\omega t/2}$ is for a standard harmonic oscillator hamiltonian $H=\hbar\omega\left(a^\dagger a+\frac12\right)$, and it drops out if one ignores the zero-point energy term.